# Ubuntu Suspend won't wake by mouse

Tags: 11.04, suspend, system, sleep

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and realized that suspend would not wake by either keyboard or mouse.  After following instructions from here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642817
The system will now wake by keyboard.

I have a USB mouse it is a Logitech G5.  Even if I enable all of the USB devices listed in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`, my computer will still not wake up via mouse.

I'd really prefer to wake by mouse instead of keyboard due to cats.  Does anyone know why my mouse won't wake the machine even after enabling all USB devices listed?

Comment: Could you please list the manufacturer and model of your PC?  It would really help in diagnosing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also, Ubuntu 11.10 came with a lot of new drivers and driver updates. Updating to 11.10 might fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  I am on 11.10 and still have this issue.  My PC is custom built.  Its a gigabyte motherboard, I don't remember the model number but can find out later.

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange. Does it wake by mouse with a non-wireless one?

Comment: Help, now I realize your mouse isn't wireless. Does it wake up with other mice?

Comment: I tried a different mouse in a couple different USB ports still no dice.  It seems to have no problem waking up from suspend via keyboard, but not like using my mice.

Comment: That is real strange. I'm not sure what to say. Can you file a bug report on launchpad? Still, this is a difficult one to describe in a bug report...

Comment: Sometimes there are mice which switch themselves off after a certain amount of time. You have to awake those by pressing a mouse button. Just moving the mouse does nothing. Could it be that you have this kind of mouse?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!